# Swap numbers from different lines (from fileinput library) without using temporary variables

Tags: python, swap

I am aware that there are similar posts. But none of them seems to deal with input from the file input library. My biggest problem here is that I don't know how to handle each `line` generated from the for loop without assigning a temporary variable.

I am doing a code practice question where the requirement is to "Write a function to swap two numbers ***without*** using any temporary variables."

And the code I was given to start the question is:

```
import fileinput
import sys

for line in fileinput.input():
```

I am aware that in python, swapping numbers can be as easy as `x,y = y,x`, or it can be:

```
x = x^y
y = x^y
x = x^y
```

But how can I do it when there is no `x` or `y` assigned here?

My solution so far is this:

```
import fileinput
import sys

l = []

for line in fileinput.input():
    l.append(line)
l = l[::-1]
for e in l:
    print(e)
```

But I'm not sure if I have violated the rules by introducing `l`.

Input example:

```
5
10
```

Expected output:

```
10
5
```

Comment: Do you think you're allowed to at least create `l` but add items to it in reverse? i.e. `l.insert(0, line)`

Comment: @edd, thanks for the response. I'm not sure and that's why I asked this question. To me, this question doesn't make much sense. But your solution is indeed better than mine.

Comment: I think introducing `l` violates the rules. What is the format of each line of the file—i.e where exactly are these numbers to be swapped? Might be best for you to show sample input and expected output.

Comment: @martineau that's a very good question. I forgot to add that. Allow me to do it now. They are just integers.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me. They didn't say anything about not writing to a temporary file right? :)

```
import fileinput
import os
import sys

l = []

for line in fileinput.input():
    open('test.txt', 'a').write(line)
print('\n'.join(open('test.txt').read().split('\n')[-2::-1]))
```

Comment: No, indeed they did not. This is a good approach. Could the `[-2::-1]`bit be replaced by `[::-1]`?

Comment: I tried using `[::-1]` but I noticed the `read()` add an extra new line at the end when reading from text file even though there's none in the `test.txt` file, so the list created by the `split('\n')` will look something like `['<first number>', '<second number>', '']`. I decided to slice out that last empty string in the list so that it won't add new line to the end when I use the `\`\n\`.join()` function.